# Group values by day

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by, pivot

**I'm using Oracle 11g,**
**Plsql version 10.0.1**

I fetch a daily report for Product_Status. Once the raw data come. I make a pivot from the raw data and group it by product sales by date column in MS Excel. I want to do the same thing in the query itself.

**product sales date format** : 3/12/2014 7:57:27 AM
**Tbl_Name** : tv_productdetails

**Plain Sql Query**
Below is the sample query for product details :

```
Select product.id, Product_Sales_Date
from smspadm.tv_productdetails
where 
Product_Sales_Date >= TO_DATE('01-april-2014','DD-MON-YYYY')
and Product_Sales_Date < TO_DATE('04-april-2014','DD-MON-YYYY')
and product_status in('active')
```

The expected output would be:

```
product.id 1-Apr 2-Apr 3-Apr 4-Apr Grandtotal

A011          89     89   89    89  356
B055          85     85   85    85  340
C055          78     78   78    78  312
D011          98     98   98    98  392
E897          45     45   45    45  180
```

I need only two columns Product.id, Product_Sales_Date to group the data by sales date.
Below is the sample data:

```
Product.id  Product_Sales_Date

A001    4/12/2014 3:38:00 PM
A002    4/13/2014 3:38:00 PM
A003    4/14/2014 11:34:34 AM
A004    4/15/2014 12:56:52 PM
A001    4/16/2014 10:54:58 AM
A002    4/17/2014 9:01:19 AM
A003    4/18/2014 12:56:52 PM
A004    4/19/2014 3:38:00 PM
A005    4/20/2014 1:07:49 PM
A006    4/21/2014 3:02:14 PM
A004    4/22/2014 10:55:54 AM
A005    4/23/2014 3:16:28 PM
A006    4/24/2014 8:46:48 AM
A007    4/25/2014 3:53:32 PM
A008    4/26/2014 7:57:27 AM
```

Comment: As per what you have described you can use PIVOT. Please provide some sample data so that we can work on it.

Comment: Sample data updated..

Comment: you need to use Dynamic PIVOT.

Comment: There is no PIVOT in 10g @AK47... It was introduced in 11.1.

Comment: Oh! sorry, I know SQL Server very well. So how we can achieve this goal?

Comment: Issue not resolved..any further response will be highly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

I have never worked on 10g, still sharing some LOGIC prepared on SQL Server,

```
Declare @cols varchar(max) = ''
Declare @query varchar(max) = ''

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',Case When Datediff(dd,sDate,' +
                        QUOTENAME(Cast(sDate as Date),'''')  + ') = 0 then 1 else 0 end as ' + QUOTENAME(Cast(sDate as Date),'') val
                      FROM tv_productdetails
                      ORDER BY val asc
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '')
Select @cols                        

SELECT @query = 'select productid, ' + @cols +' from tv_productdetails '

execute(@query)
```

Hope it helps you. further output can be grouped together to achieve what you have asked, don't know that all the things I have used are there or not in 10g.

Comment: Issue not resolved..any further response will be highly appreciated